# Implement distance matrix in knn in R

Tags: r, matrix, apply, knn

i want to calulate the distance matrix in R (using Euclidean distance)

i know how to do it in for loop

but how can i do it using apply family fucntion ?

```
require(magrittr)

data(iris)

set.seed(1)
data <- iris[sample(nrow(iris))   ,] # 打散資料
Xtrain <- data[1:100,1:4]
Xtest <- data[101:150,1:4]

M <- nrow(Xtrain)
N <- nrow(Xtest)

distmatrix <- matrix(0,nrow = M,ncol = N)

for(i in 1:M){
  for(j in 1:N){
    distmatrix[i,j]<- sum((Xtrain[i,]-Xtest[j,])^2) %>% sqrt()
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `mapply` with `expand.grid` for all combinations of `M` and `N`:

```
params <- expand.grid(M=seq(M), N=seq(N))

distmatrix2 <- matrix(mapply(function(i,j) sqrt(sum((Xtrain[i,]-Xtest[j,])^2)), 
                      params$M, params$N),
                      nrow = M, ncol = N)

# EQUIVALENT TO OP's distance 
identical(distmatrix, distmatrix2)
# TRUE
```

Comment: @陳寧寬, `matrix` is needed to convert the vector returned from `mapply`. And the reason a vector is returned is because your function returns a single value per each iteration and as a result loses the original row and column dimensions.